# NetCDF with negative dimensions

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, netcdf, rasterstats

I am trying to read a NetCDF file with rasterio (Python), however, the resulting affine is showing negative numbers.

The .nc4 file comes from NOAA. How can I correct these negative dimensions?

```
nc_fo = r'./hist2/precip.nc4'
affine = rio.open(nc_fo).transform
affine
```

result:

```
Affine(0.1000000050890903, 0.0, -89.99999695078674,
   0.0, 0.09999999830410791, -179.99999694739424)
```

Comment: Seems to be dimensions of a translation column vector for the the most southwesterly node,  and they seem to have correct values.

Comment: rasterstats does not recognize those negative dimensions.

Comment: maybe you can try to reproject it to "+proj=lonlat +datum=WGS84 +lon_wrap=180 +type=crs"

Comment: thank you! should i try to use that on gdalwarp?

Comment: The negative numbers show the georeferenced origin of the data.  Have you perhaps interpreted them to express the size of your raster, or what do you mean by dimensions?

Comment: Can you show what you do with rasterstats? Or what rasterstats complains about?

Comment: rasterstats netCDF enhancement: https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats/issues/97, Multiband support: https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats/issues/73. Seems to me simpler to extract a dimension to a raster band and reproject it, but not tested.